# How can I define a sparse array in one statement in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

As an example, I am doing this

```lua
local Bool = {} 
Bool [false]='OFF' 
Bool [true]='ON'
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't

```lua
local Bool = {false='OFF', true='ON'}
```

How can I define it in one statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation you are trying to use only works when the indices can be written as identifiers, so alphanumeric + underscore, for any other values, numbers, weird strings, booleans, tables or functions, you want to use

```
myTable = {[false] = "some value", [-1/12] = 0}
```

You need to enclose indices in square brackets.

Btw that's not a multidimensional array

Comment: Yes, I know it is not multi-dimensional.  I also noted that I was using an example.  I can expand from this to what I need, myself.